# Symfony2 Avoiding duplicate/repeated properties in security.yml with multiple firewalls

Tags: symfony, yaml

In my application, I have two firewalls in security.yml (Example provided below). As you can see, the "admin_secured_area" and the "account_secured_area" firewalls have very similar properties, with just the occasional variation. I would like to know is there a way to avoid having the common properties entered 2 times. For example could I inherit the properties from a base (parent) firewall? or can I import the properties needed from a single location? or any other alternative?

```
  security:
      firewalls:
          admin_secured_area:
              stateless: true
              lexik_jwt:
                  authorization_header:
                      enabled: false
                  query_parameter:
                      enabled: true
                      name:    lexiktoken
                  throw_exceptions: true
                  create_entry_point: true
              entry_point: foobar.authentication_handler
              provider: in_memory
              pattern:    ^/admin
              form_login:
                  username_parameter: username
                  password_parameter: password
                  require_previous_session: false
                  success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                  failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                  check_path:  /admin/login
              logout:
                  path:   /admin/logout
                  success_handler: foobar.authentication_handler

          account_secured_area:
              stateless: true
              lexik_jwt:
                  authorization_header:
                      enabled: false
                  query_parameter:
                      enabled: true
                      name:    lexiktoken
                  throw_exceptions: true
                  create_entry_point: true
              entry_point: foobar.authentication_handler
              provider:   user_db
              pattern:    ^(/account)|(/reset-password)
              form_login:
                  username_parameter: username
                  password_parameter: password
                  require_previous_session: false
                  success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                  failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                  check_path:   /account/login
              logout:
                  path:   /account/logout
                  success_handler: foobar.authentication_handler
```

Answer (score 3):

Using parameters should be possible. See my example for the config key "lexik_jwt".

```
  security:
      parameters:
          lexik_jwt_settings: 
              authorization_header:
                      enabled: false
                  query_parameter:
                      enabled: true
                      name:    lexiktoken
                  throw_exceptions: true
                  create_entry_point: true
      firewalls:
          admin_secured_area:
              stateless: true
              lexik_jwt: %lexik_jwt_settings%
              entry_point: foobar.authentication_handler
              provider: in_memory
              pattern:    ^/admin
              form_login:
                  username_parameter: username
                  password_parameter: password
                  require_previous_session: false
                  success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                  failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                  check_path:  /admin/login
              logout:
                  path:   /admin/logout
                  success_handler: foobar.authentication_handler

          account_secured_area:
              stateless: true
              lexik_jwt: %lexik_jwt_settings%
              entry_point: foobar.authentication_handler
              provider:   user_db
              pattern:    ^(/account)|(/reset-password)
              form_login:
                  username_parameter: username
                  password_parameter: password
                  require_previous_session: false
                  success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                  failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                  check_path:   /account/login
              logout:
                  path:   /account/logout
                  success_handler: foobar.authentication_handler
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sebbo, I will implement what you have suggested. Ideally I am looking for a solution where I could define all the "base" parameters, and then for each individual firewall just override a few of the properties. (Similar to what you could do with .ini files in Zend Framework 1)

Comment: @Sam have a look here, I think it's what you were looking for: http://rhnh.net/2011/01/31/yaml-tutorial